# Cucumber - How to write a test case to change the sort ordering of items listed in a table?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I am sort of new to cucumber and have gotten hung up on a test case.

There is a table on a page which lists a bunch of products, one of the cells contains up & down graphics - these are controls which the user clicks on to move the sort ordering of that product up or down in a catalogue which the end user can browse.

How can I select the 2nd product listed in the table, find its id & click on its "up" or down link?

Here is the table (shortened for readability):

```
<table id="product_container">
 <tr>
   <th>Order Position</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><a href="#" class="product_up"   id="product_sku_goes_here">Up</a>
       <a href="#" class="product_down" id="product_sku_goes_here">Down</a>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute of HTML element needs to be unique on the page: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

The easiest way to select product would be to get a reference to it's row:

```
class ProductsTable
  def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
  end

  def table
    @driver.find_element(:id, "product_container")
  end

  def products
    table.find_elements(:tag_name, "td").map{|element|
      Products.new(element)
    }
  end
end

class Products
  def initialize(element)
    @elem = element
  end

  def up
    @elem.find_element(:class, "product_up")
  end

  def down
    @elem.find_element(:class, "product_down")
  end
end

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get "http://link_to_testing_page"
tabl = ProductsTable.new(driver)
```

To push first product up:

```
tabl.products.first.up.click
```

down:

```
tabl.products.first.down.click
```

Cucumber step definition:

```
When /^I push product (\d+) (.*)$/ do |product, where|
  product = product.to_i - 1
  tabl.products[product].send(where).click
end
```